# 09 ford flex A/C is blowing warm, Compressor clicking on and runny,pressure on low side well over 100

Tags: ford, hvac, flex

AC worked fine find about a week ago and then just stop stop working,  got a couple of cans of freon and  Hooked up the connection  and the pressure was showing very high very high almost to the top of the red scale

Comment: Why did you add refrigerant?  Was it low on pressure before you added some?

Comment: Does the low pressure reading change when the compressor has kicked on and when it is off?  Does your AC fan kick on when you turn on the AC?

Comment: I didn't add any freon just hook up the Guage to it to see if it needed a  charge it didn't  it was hi around  90 that's my concern , I'll check the fan,and the pressure  didn't change with the compressor turning on

Comment: So the compressor was running and the low side was showing over 90 psi?  Could you see the centre shaft of the compressor turning, or only the outer pulley?  It sounds like the compressor isn’t doing anything.